# Whats the difference between this lseek, fseek, read, fread?

Tags: c

I am calling these functions:

```
unsigned blah[5];
lseek(0, 100, SEEK_CUR);
read(0, blah, sizeof(blah));
```

and

```
FILE *fr;
fr = fopen(arg[1], "r");
unsigned blah[5];
fseek(fr, 100, SEEK_CUR);
fread(blah, 1, sizeof(blah), fr);
```

And I run the first code my running this command:

```
cat TEXTFILE | ./a.out
```

I run the second code my running this command:

```
./a.out TEXTFILE
```

However, I am getting different results. While the first one seeked properly, so it reads the correct text, the second one is not. I want to use the second format, so what did I do wrong?

Comment: what happens if you use fseek with SEEK_SET?

Comment: also, just as a check, how many read does 'read' return and how many does fread return?

Comment: Maybe you ought to explain why you are trying to read *unsigned ints* from a text file.  Reading characters works better, strtol() to convert.  And no seek, use fgets()

Comment: what do u mean how many does it return?

Comment: You should always check system calls for errors.  If you did that, you'd know that your `lseek()` failed and set `errno` to ESPIPE (illegal seek).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the addition of an `open(filename,O_RDONLY);` call to the first example, both worked fine for me. I suspect your problem is because of the call `lseek(0, 100, SEEK_CUR);`, which is asking for a seek on standard input. You cannot always seek on standard in - if you have:

```
 cat file | ./my_program
```

Then standard input is a fifo, and you can't seek. If I do this on my system, seek fails by returning `-1`, with an error of "Illegal seek". This may be the problem you're having, and you might not notice since you don't check the return value of the seek call in your example.

Note that if you have:

```
 ./my_program < file
```

Then standard input is a file, and you may seek. On my system, seek returns `100`, and the output is correct.

---

Here is a program you can use to illustrate the return values:

```
int main(void){ 

  int fd = 0;
  char blah[5];
  printf("Seek moved to this position: %d\n",lseek(fd, 100, SEEK_CUR));
  perror("Seek said");
  printf("Then read read %d bytes\n",read(fd, blah, sizeof(blah)));
  printf("The bytes read were '%c%c%c%c%c'\n",blah[0],blah[1],blah[2],blah[3],blah[4]); 
}
```

And here are two executions:

```
 $ ./a.out < text
 Seek moved to this position: 100
 Seek said: Success
 Then read read 5 bytes
 The bytes read were '+++.-'
```

(Those are the correct bytes from position 100 in that file)

```
$ cat text | ./a.out 
Seek moved to this position: -1
Seek said: Illegal seek
Then read read 5 bytes
The bytes read were '# def'
```

(Those bytes are the first 5 bytes of the file)

---

I also noticed that the standard input version was the one you said was working correctly. If you're having trouble with the `FILE *` version, I suspect the `fopen()` call is failing, so make sure you check the return value from `fopen()`. Of course, you can always do this:

```
FILE *fr = stdin;
```

So that you're reading from standard in. **However, as you can't always seek on standard in, I'd recommend always opening a file if you plan to seek.**

Note that you can't seek on all devices that you can open files on (though you won't have a problem on most systems), so you should always check that the result of a `seek()` to make sure it succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a 100% sure about the difference, but it seems to be related to pipe vs stdio/file.  To illustrate this, I made these 2 different test programs:

exam.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char blah[5] = {0,};

        /* we're using stdin instead of pipeline  :( */
        lseek(0, 100, SEEK_CUR);
        read(0, blah, sizeof(blah));

        printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n", blah[0], blah[1], blah[2], blah[3], blah[4]);

        return 0;
}
```

test.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void testA(const char *s)
{
        int f = -1;
        char blah[5] = {0,};

        f = open(s, O_RDONLY);

        if (-1 < f)
        {
                lseek(f, 100, SEEK_CUR);
                read(f, blah, sizeof(blah));
        }

        printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n", blah[0], blah[1], blah[2], blah[3], blah[4]);
}

void testB(const char *s)
{
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        char blah[5] = {0,};

        fp = fopen(s, "r");

        if (fp)
        {
                fseek(fp, 100, SEEK_CUR);
                fread(blah, 1, sizeof(blah), fp);
        }

        printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n", blah[0], blah[1], blah[2], blah[3], blah[4]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        testA(argv[1]);
        testB(argv[1]);

        return 0;
}
```

Then I created some test data.

data.txt

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

When I executed `cat ./data.txt | ./exam`, the output is

```
01234
```

When I executed `./test ./data.txt`, I got

```
bcdef
bcdef
```

Just FYI, the results remain unchanged even if we replace `SEEK_CUR` with `SEEK_SET`.

However, `./exam <./data.txt` results in

```
bcdef
```

which is legitimate.

I know this is not an acceptable answer without knowing why '0' brings up the data file's contents, but I hope it helps somehow.

Comment: I added an answer explaining the difference between piping and redirecting :)

Comment: You could - arguably should in this context - check the return status from `lseek()`, which would give you -1 and set `errno` to ESPIPE.

Comment: @TimothyJones +1 Thanks for the explanation!  :D  ...didn't know stdin is unseekable.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that it's not *always* unseekable - just sometimes, depending on how it's provided. Generally, I don't think it's good practice to seek on stdin.

Answer (score 2):

SEEK_CUR starts from the current position. That is why your first seek works when you are at the beginning of the file. To always seek from the beginning you need to use SEEK_SET instead of SEEK_CUR.

```
0   SEEK_SET    The beginning of the file
1   SEEK_CUR    The current position
2   SEEK_END    The end of the file
```