# hard disk acces fseeko and fread vs lseek and read

Tags: linux, fread, hard-drive, fseek, lseek

is there any difference between using `fseeko` with `fread` vs `lseek` with `read` if I want to do Hard disk access ?

My program checks for certain patterns on a raw harddisk (`/dev/sdX`). My program currently uses `fseeko` and `fread`.

Platform is linux.

Comment: You could just read the man pages... http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseeko.3.html

Comment: some people here talk about bytes not being read etc... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349470/whats-the-difference-between-fseek-lseek-seekg-seekp

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349470/whats-the-difference-between-fseek-lseek-seekg-seekp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888419/whats-the-difference-between-this-lseek-fseek-read-fread